# How to make a custom method available in Pry console

Tags: ruby, debugging, pry

I've been writing this into my Pry console to find the stack trace scoped to my app:

```rb
caller.select {|line| line.include? "myapp" }
```

Is there a way to make this a method and just call something like `my_stack` instead?

How can I do this?

Comment: https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Custom-commands#where-to-put-your-commands

Comment: Please don't add summaries of the solution to your question. On SO questions are only that, and answers are separate. If you feel you reached the fix without help from others then it's appropriate to create an answer and select it as the solution, otherwise upvote and select the answer that helped solve it. "[What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267434/128421)"

Comment: See https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Custom-commands for more information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your home directory (`~`), you can create a file named `.pryrc` and put a Ruby function in it:

```ruby
def my_stack(app_name = '')
  caller.select {|line| line.include? app_name }
end
```

And you can use `my_stack` or `my_stack('myapp')` from Pry.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@vcsjones answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60121628/128421), I added the following to `~/.pryrc`:

```rb
def my_stack(needle = File.basename(Dir.getwd))
  caller.select {|line| line.include? needle }
end
```

which will, by default, scope to the directory the application is running in.